# RoR: Devise signup form on home page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I'm having trouble getting user registration form to work when I have it in my home page. It keeps sending me to `localhost:3000/signup` page (it sends me there because of validation purposes and shows the errors)

This form is in my `layouts/index.html.erb` page

```
<%= form_for(resource, :as => resource_name, :url => registration_path(resource_name)) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= button_tag :type => :submit do %>
    Sign up
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

This is what my routes look like:

```
devise_for :users,
           :skip => [:sessions],
           :controllers => { registrations: "users/registrations", omniauth_callbacks: "omniauth_callbacks" }
  devise_scope :user do
    get 'signup/' => 'devise/registrations#new', :as => :new_user_registration 
    post 'signup/' => 'users/registrations#create', :as => :user_registration 
  end
end

authenticated :user do
  root :to => "dashboard#show"
end
unauthenticated :user do
  devise_scope :user do
    root :to => "static#home"
  end
end
```

This is what my `static#home` looks like

```
def home
  render :layout => "layouts/index"
end
```

Please help

Comment: why are you skipping the sessions controller? are you implementing that somewhere else? Usually you skip the controllers you want to override or manually take care of.

Answer (score 1):

Update the 'layout/index,erb' file

```
<%= form_for(User.new, :url => new_user_registration_path) do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :username %>
  <%= f.email_field :email %>
  <%= f.password_field :password %>
  <%= button_tag :type => :submit do %>
    Sign up
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

and don't try to skip, Please override your controller action

```
devise_for :users, controllers: { sessions: "users/sessions" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your problem is you want to render `static#home` if you've got an error (instead of `registrations#new`)

--

**`form_for`**

The problem you have is your Rails app is redirecting to the `model` route for your `registrations` controller (I.E `registrations#new`)

When you use `form_for` (I.E create a new ActiveRecord object), Rails redirects to the route it deems is necessary to render the form with errors (I.E `registrations#new`):

> Typically, a form designed to create or update a resource reflects the
>   identity of the resource in several ways: (i) the url that the form is
>   sent to (the form element's action attribute) should result in a
>   request being routed to the appropriate controller action (with the
>   appropriate :id parameter in the case of an existing resource)

--

**Ajax**

I could be talking rubbish here (I don't have any references), but what I would include the sign up form as an **`ajax / remote` form**, and then send the appropriate data via ajax, receiving a return which you can display on your homepage.

We've done something similar with our [cosmetics app](http://firststopcosmeticshop.co.uk) (click "register" at top):

[image]

This works by keeping the functionality in the `registrations#new` contorller, but allows you to use the registration process on the homepage.

--

**Code**

Here is the code we used - please note that you can include the form "in-line" (on the homepage directly), you don't need to include it in a popover like we did:

```
#app/controllers/registrations_controller.rb
class RegistrationsController < DeviseController
  prepend_before_filter :require_no_authentication, :only => [ :new, :create, :cancel ]
  prepend_before_filter :authenticate_scope!, :only => [:edit, :update, :destroy]

  before_filter :configure_permitted_parameters

  prepend_view_path 'app/views/devise'

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  def new
    build_resource({})
    respond_with self.resource
  end

  # POST /resource
  def create
    build_resource(sign_up_params)

    if resource.save
      if resource.active_for_authentication?
        set_flash_message :notice, :signed_up if is_navigational_format?
        sign_up(resource_name, resource)
        respond_with resource, :location => after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      else
        set_flash_message :notice, :"signed_up_but_#{resource.inactive_message}" if is_navigational_format?
        expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
        respond_with resource, :location => after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
      end
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource

      respond_to do |format|
        format.json { render :json => resource.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
        format.html { respond_with resource }
      end
    end
  end

  # GET /resource/edit
  def edit
    render :edit
  end

  # PUT /resource
  # We need to use a copy of the resource because we don't want to change
  # the current user in place.
  def update
    self.resource = resource_class.to_adapter.get!(send(:"current_#{resource_name}").to_key)
    prev_unconfirmed_email = resource.unconfirmed_email if resource.respond_to?(:unconfirmed_email)

    if update_resource(resource, account_update_params)
      if is_navigational_format?
        flash_key = update_needs_confirmation?(resource, prev_unconfirmed_email) ?
          :update_needs_confirmation : :updated
        set_flash_message :notice, flash_key
      end
      sign_in resource_name, resource, :bypass => true
      respond_with resource, :location => after_update_path_for(resource)
    else
      clean_up_passwords resource
      respond_with resource
    end
  end

  # DELETE /resource
  def destroy
    resource.destroy
    Devise.sign_out_all_scopes ? sign_out : sign_out(resource_name)
    set_flash_message :notice, :destroyed if is_navigational_format?
    respond_with_navigational(resource){ redirect_to after_sign_out_path_for(resource_name) }
  end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  def cancel
    expire_session_data_after_sign_in!
    redirect_to new_registration_path(resource_name)
  end

  protected

  # Custom Fields
  def configure_permitted_parameters
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.for(:sign_up) do |u|
      u.permit(:first_name, :last_name,
        :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end
  end

  def update_needs_confirmation?(resource, previous)
    resource.respond_to?(:pending_reconfirmation?) &&
      resource.pending_reconfirmation? &&
      previous != resource.unconfirmed_email
  end

  # By default we want to require a password checks on update.
  # You can overwrite this method in your own RegistrationsController.
  def update_resource(resource, params)
    resource.update_with_password(params)
  end

  # Build a devise resource passing in the session. Useful to move
  # temporary session data to the newly created user.
  def build_resource(hash=nil)
    self.resource = resource_class.new_with_session(hash || {}, session)
  end

  # Signs in a user on sign up. You can overwrite this method in your own
  # RegistrationsController.
  def sign_up(resource_name, resource)
    sign_in(resource_name, resource)
  end

  # The path used after sign up. You need to overwrite this method
  # in your own RegistrationsController.
  def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    after_sign_in_path_for(resource)
  end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts. You need to overwrite
  # this method in your own RegistrationsController.
  def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
    respond_to?(:root_path) ? root_path : "/"
  end

  # The default url to be used after updating a resource. You need to overwrite
  # this method in your own RegistrationsController.
  def after_update_path_for(resource)
    signed_in_root_path(resource)
  end

  # Authenticates the current scope and gets the current resource from the session.
  def authenticate_scope!
    send(:"authenticate_#{resource_name}!", :force => true)
    self.resource = send(:"current_#{resource_name}")
  end

  def sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:sign_up)
  end

  def account_update_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.sanitize(:account_update)
  end
end
```

This will allow you to change the `devise` `registration` form to use `remote: :json`, as follows:

```
#app/views/devise/registrations/new.html.erb
<%= form_for(devise_resource, :as => devise_resource_name, :html => {:id => 'register_form'}, :url => user_registration_path, :remote => :true, :format => :json) do |f| %>
```